# Microsoft Bot Framework NodeJS V4 running on AWS Lambda 401 unauthorized error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, botframework

I am trying to build a Chatbot using the MS BotFramework running Serverless at AWS Lambda.

The Bot is working with the Emulator and NGROK when no AppId and AppSecret are specified:

```
 var adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
        appId: null,
        appPassword: null
    });
```

When I enable the AppId and Password:

```
 var adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
        appId: process.env.microsoftAppID,
        appPassword: process.env.microsoftAppPassword
    });
```

The Emulator responds with:
Cannot post activity. Unauthorized to a message

And in the logs I get this: 
BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity(): 401 ERROR - Error: Unauthorized Access. Request is not authorized

I already verified the credentials with Step 2 from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-authentication-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#issue-an-http-request-to-the-microsoft-login-service

Comment: You've created these lambda function environment variables? microsoftAppID and microsoftAppPassword and are supplying them to the emulator when attempting to connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code is working now for me. There was a new update for the npm "botbuilder" package published that fixed the problem.